# Unable to create cmis:document inside custom alfresco folder

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I'm using open cmis to create folder (custom type) with attachments in Alfresco repository (5.1e). Folder is successfully created, but for creation of document (cmis:document - cm:content) as attachment I'm getting following exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConstraintException: Objects of type 'cmis:document' cannot be added to this folder!
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:514) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:717) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:122) [chemistry-opencmis-client-bindings-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:1197) [chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:88) [chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:471) [chemistry-opencmis-client-impl-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
>                   at com.salviol.frops.common.ejbs.DcmIntegrationEJB.createDocument(DcmIntegrationEJB.java:208) [frops-common-ejb-0.0.1.jar:]
>                   at com.salviol.frops.common.ejbs.DcmIntegrationEJB.createCase(DcmIntegrationEJB.java:67) [frops-common-ejb-0.0.1.jar:]
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
>                   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
>                   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
>                   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>                   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
>                   ... 174 more

Here is the source code  (method) for adding document to folder:

```
private Document createDocument(Session cmisSession, Folder parentFolder, byte[] file, String fileName, String fileType) {

Document document = null;

try {

Map<String, Object> docProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();    
docProperties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,  "cmis:document");
docProperties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, fileName);

    ContentStream contentStream = cmisSession.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(fileName, file.length, fileType, new ByteArrayInputStream(file));

        document = parentFolder.createDocument(docProperties, contentStream, null);

    } catch (CmisContentAlreadyExistsException ccaee) {
        document = (Document) cmisSession.getObjectByPath(parentFolder.getPath() + "/" + fileName);            
    }

    return document;
}
```

I tried with versioning (state MAJOR and NONE), but the problem is still there. Created folder has standard permissions (inherit = "true" and for each site user appropriate permission).

Did anyone have the same problem with Cmis constraint?

Answer (score 1):

It's about your folder, not about your document.
Take a look at the code that is causing the error, and the cause will become aparent. There's a property named `cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds`, and it's what you're after.

How is your model defined?

```
public void checkChildObjectType(CMISNodeInfo folderInfo, String childType)
    {
        TypeDefinitionWrapper targetType = folderInfo.getType();
        PropertyDefinitionWrapper allowableChildObjectTypeProperty = targetType
                .getPropertyById(PropertyIds.ALLOWED_CHILD_OBJECT_TYPE_IDS);
        List<String> childTypes = (List<String>) allowableChildObjectTypeProperty.getPropertyAccessor().getValue(
                folderInfo);

        if ((childTypes == null) || childTypes.isEmpty())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!childTypes.contains(childType))
        {
            throw new CmisConstraintException("Objects of type '" + childType + "' cannot be added to this folder!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Custom model is defined on alfresco repo side and  contains custom type that extends cm:folder type (with its custom properties, aspect and associations). Where is the right place for adding  cmis:allowedChildObjectTypeIds, alfresco repo side (custom model) or additional property on cmis creation folder?